# How to export a React Component without ownProps when using redux with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript with react-redux . I have the following component which doesn't take any "OwnProp" from parent but takes a prop from redux state. Redux is giving me error from Parent Component that it expects the prop totalRows from parent . How do i fix this  ?

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface ChatSectionStateProp{
    totalRows : number 
}

export const ChatSection: React.SFC<ChatSectionStateProp> = (prop) => {
    const totalRows = prop.totalRows
    return (
        <div style={{ 
                backgroundColor: '#5A657B' , 
                overflowY:'scroll' , 
                gridColumn:'3 / 13' , 
                gridRow:`2 / ${totalRows+1}` 
        }} >

        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:ChatSectionStateProp)=>{
    totalRows : state.totalRows
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatSection) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i wasn't exporting only the connected component but also the original Component . Removing the export did the work. Here's the modified code.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface ChatSectionStateProp{
    totalRows : number 
}

const ChatSection: React.FC<ChatSectionStateProp> = (prop) => {
    const totalRows = prop.totalRows
    return (
        <div style={{ 
                backgroundColor: '#5A657B' , 
                overflowY:'scroll' , 
                gridColumn:'3 / 13' , 
                gridRow:`2 / ${totalRows+1}` 
        }} >

        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:ChatSectionStateProp)=>({
    totalRows : state.totalRows
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatSection) ;
```